# Json.net serialize only part of array

Tags: c#, arrays, json, serialization

could anybody tell me how to serialize and deserialize only part of array `tools[]` without `Func` delegate where:

```
    public class Tool
    {
        public Tool()
        {
            lastUse = 1;
            running = false;
        }
        public Func<int> action;
        public bool running;
        public int lastUse;
    }
    public static Tool[] tools = new Tool[] { new Tool(), new Tool(), new Tool(),new Tool()};
```

Thanks in advance for any responses.

Comment: Can you show your data which you want to serialize to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing you can do is take advantage of the [DataContract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx) and [DataMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.aspx) attributes to only serialize the data you want.

```
[DataContract]
public class Tool
{
    public Tool()
    {
        lastUse = 1;
        running = false;
    }

    public Func<int> action;

    [DataMember]
    public bool running;

    [DataMember]
    public int lastUse;
}
```

The result without the attributes:

```
[{"action":null,"running":false,"lastUse":1},{"action":null,"running":false,"lastUse":1},{"action":null,"running":false,"lastUse":1},{"action":null,"running":false,"lastUse":1}]
```

With the attributes:

```
[{"running":false,"lastUse":1},{"running":false,"lastUse":1},{"running":false,"lastUse":1},{"running":false,"lastUse":1}]
```

This works with both [Json.NET](http://json.net/) and [DataContractJsonSerialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx).

What I like about this approach is it let's you keep standard C# property naming conventions, but still output "correctly cased" JSON.

```
[DataMember(Name="last_use")]
public int LastUse { get; set; }
```

will output

```
{"last_use": 1}
```